# How do catch error on React Native SQLite

Tags: sqlite, react-native, android-sqlite

I have the code:

```
let dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs
  RNFetchBlob
  .config({
    fileCache : false,
  })
  //pega o arquivo da internet
  .fetch('GET', 'https://URL_WITH_QUERY_TEXT')
  .then((res) => {
    //lê o arquivo salvo anteriormente
    db.transaction((tx) => {
        var sql = res
        tx.executeSql(sql, [], (tx, results) => {
            alert('OK!')
          })
          .catch((error) => alert(error));
      });
  })
```

I not receive none alert.

Can I catch the error correctly?

Comment: I used to catch the error in SQLite using the syntax as `tx.executeSql(sql, [], (tx,  rs) => {}, (tx, err) => {/*You can process error here*/})`.

Comment: I add `tx.executeSql(sql, [], (tx, rs) => {}, (tx, err) => {alert(err)})` but receive an alert with `undefined`. how do show the error?

Comment: Did u see what you are getting inside `tx` object? You will get information there.

Comment: @PrasunPal `[object Object]`

Comment: Print this into console, or inspect the `tx` object.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the following way after the response use comma(,) and console error callback.

```
dbConnection.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql(query, values, async (tx1) => {
          dispatch(clearTodos());
          const data = await getTodosFromDbMethod(dbConnection, 1);
        }, (error) => {
        console.log("error: " + JSON.stringify(error))
        reject(error);
    });
  });
```